# How to take id from medecin without choice field

Tags: php, symfony

I removed the choice field for medecin from the status form, and now I want to take the medecin's id from the actual medecin:

```
 $id= $entity->setMedecin();
        $form = $this->createForm(new statutType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('statut_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Ajouter'));

        return $form;
    }
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: i have two entity medecin and statut every medecin can add 0 or many status, so i stop use the property medecin in status i remove this `            ->add('medecin','entity',array('class'=>'DoctorBundle:medecin','property'=>'id','multiple'=>false)) and i want that it take id medecin from the bar adress
`

Comment: Please edit your question to add your code, do not post it in a comment.

Comment: ok, i am a new user in group so i put it in comment